# How to override laravel model query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a main model called `User` that returns all the users of the application.

There is a table called `invites` which manages the users invited to access the invitee panel. The `invites` table is thus linked to `users`:

[image]

So we have a general `User` model which handle all the users, and other two types of users:

- Patient: user who invited the tenant
- Tenant: user who has access to a list of associated patients

What I am trying to do is to fetch a patient list of a certain tenant (logged in user) using the eloquent relationship system, so I don't have to write a query for the join every time. Is it possible to do this?

At the moment, I tried this:

```
class Patient extends User
{
    use HasFactory;

    //protected $table = 'users';

    public function getList()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

but of course this relationship not works because the query that should execute must be this:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN invites i ON i.user_id = u.id 
WHERE i.tenant_id = 1
```

where id is the reference of the current user logged in which I retrieve using laratrust auth: `auth()->user()->id`.

Would be possible to return all the patients associated to the logged in user automatically? So simply calling:

```
Patient::query();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that you should define relation and reverse many to many relation:
in your user model:

```
class Tenant extends User
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function patients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites', 'tenant_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And in **Patient model** define reverse many to many relation by reverse **belongToMany** params :

```
class Patient extends User
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function tenants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites', 'user_id', 'tenant_id');
    }
}
```

To use the auth id for each model you have 2 option:

**Option 1:**

add column in users table that named user_type wich have type **enum('tenant','patient')** and depend user type use the appropriate model

**Option 2:**

by using custom auth guards , take look to this article

https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-8-login-with-custom-guard-example

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but how can I tell to the relationship to use the id of the current logged in users automatically? Could you please show a query example too? If I call `Tenant:all()` I get: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table app.tenants`

Comment: i make some edits , take look @sfarzoso

Comment: I did: `$t = new \App\Models\Tenant();` and I tried to retrieve the patients list: `$test = $t->patient;` but `$test` is empty. I forgot something?

Comment: did you create tenant and associate patients to it ? @sfarzoso

Comment: Yes, within the table `invites` I have `user_id: 2` and `tenant_id: 1`

Comment: so you should use find instead create new one : Tenant::find(1)->patients()->get()